# How to create a denormalized (always up-to-date) view using Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am trying to build a pipeline to enable de-normalized read view as per CQRS pattern for a typical micro service architecture. Say, I have three tables: `customers`, `products` and `orders` in a Postgres database. I am using Debezium for capturing the CDC events from Postgres, push those to Kafka and then build a de-normalized read view in ElasticSearch using Kafka Connect to serve filtering and aggregation queries.

For simplicity, say my Postgres tables looks as below:

**Customers:**

```
+------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Column     | Type                   | Modifiers                                               |
|------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------|
| id         | integer                |  not null default nextval('customers_id_seq'::regclass) |
| first_name | character varying(255) |  not null                                               |
| last_name  | character varying(255) |  not null                                               |
| email      | character varying(255) |  not null                                               |
+------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Products:**

```
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Column      | Type                   | Modifiers                                              |
|-------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------|
| id          | integer                |  not null default nextval('products_id_seq'::regclass) |
| name        | character varying(255) |  not null                                              |
| description | character varying(512) |                                                        |
| weight      | double precision       |                                                        |
+-------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Orders:**

```
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Column     | Type    | Modifiers                                            |
|------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------|
| id         | integer |  not null default nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass) |
| order_date | date    |  not null                                            |
| purchaser  | integer |  not null                                            |
| quantity   | integer |  not null                                            |
| product_id | integer |  not null                                            |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Orders.purchaser -> foreign key -> Customers.id
Orders.product_is -> foreign key -> Products.id

My idea is a have a flat, de-normalized view created out of three tables joined on the above relationships.

I am using kSQL DB to process the Kafka Streams and here is what I have done using `KSQL`:

- Create Customer Stream:

```
CREATE STREAM customers (id INTEGER, first_name VARCHAR, last_name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='customers_topic',VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

- Create Product Stream:

```
CREATE STREAM products (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR, description VARCHAR, weight DOUBLE) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='products_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

- Create Orders Stream:

```
CREATE STREAM orders (id INTEGER, order_date DATE, purchaser INTEGER, quantity INTEGER, product_id INTEGER) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='orders_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

- Create Materialized view for Customers on Customers Stream:

```
CREATE TABLE CX_DIM AS SELECT
  CUSTOMERS.ID ID,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(CUSTOMERS.FIRST_NAME) FIRST_NAME,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(CUSTOMERS.LAST_NAME) LAST_NAME,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(CUSTOMERS.EMAIL) EMAIL
FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID
EMIT CHANGES;
```

- Create a Materialized view for Products on Products Stream:

```
CREATE TABLE PR_DIM AS SELECT
  PRODUCTS.ID ID,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(PRODUCTS.NAME) NAME,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(PRODUCTS.DESCRIPTION) DESCRIPTION,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(PRODUCTS.WEIGHT) WEIGHT
FROM PRODUCTS
GROUP BY PRODUCTS.ID
EMIT CHANGES;
```

- Create a new stream for the de-normalized read view by joining `ORDERS` stream, `CX_DIM` table and `PR_DIM` table:

```
CREATE STREAM ELASTIC_VIEW AS
SELECT
    c.ID as Cx_ID,
    c.FIRST_NAME as Cx_FNAME,
    c.LAST_NAME as Cx_LNAME, 
    c.EMAIL as Cx_EMAIL,    
    p.ID as P_ID,
    p.NAME as P_Name,         
    p.DESCRIPTION as P_Description,     
    p.WEIGHT as P_Weight,   
    o.ID as O_ID,         
    o.ORDER_DATE as O_Date, 
    o.QUANTITY as O_Qty
FROM orders o 
join CX_DIM c
ON o.purchaser=c.id 
join PR_DIM p
ON o.product_id=p.id 
emit changes;
```

The above stream is then fed to a ElasticSearch Sink connector. When a new order is created, the read view is updated with the new record joined across orders, customers and products and the same is visible in ElasticSearch index.

Now, the actual problem where I need help:

When a customer's data is updated (say change in email address), I want the *read view to be updated for older records as well*. Meaning, the read view should be the current source of truth.  But the same is not working with the above approach followed. After a customer data is updated, the same is reflected only for the new orders. However the updated data is reflected in the `CX_DIM` table created in Kafka. I am confused, if my dimension table is updated, why not the view is updated with which `orders` stream is joined.

Not sure what I am missing here. Is it even possible? Any help will be highly appreciated.